# AS3 - Keep getting a "Package is Unexpected" error in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to use one of Adobe's examples to put a video player in my Flash application using ActionScript 3 in Flash CS5.  It's the one at the bottom of the page here:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#buffering

I'm putting the ActionScript into the frame I want to play the video in.  When I try to test it, I keep getting the following error message:

"1083: Syntax error: package is unexpected"

So I try taking the "package { }" code out and running it again.  Then this error pops up:

"The public attribute can only be used inside a package"

I tried removing all the code inside the package and I still get the first error.

Might anyone know what's going on here?  I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure out / find the solution.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a class definition. You can't put it directly onto the timeline. You need to create a file `FLVPlaybackExample.as` with that source code in it.

Then, as explained in the instructions above it, set the Document class of the timeline to `FLVPlaybackExample`. This setting is in the properties window when the Stage is selected.

(edit: sorry, not quite right instructions there)

---

Alternatively, if you're against classfiles, you should be able to get the same effect by placing this on the timeline (untested):

```
player.source = "http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/caption_video.flv";
player.skinBackgroundColor = 0x666666;
player.skinBackgroundAlpha = 0.5;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was actually unaware you could include separate .as files in your Flash project.  That worked.